# How to delete all duplicate record but except one in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I tried to delete   multiple record without single

Input:

```
    Id  Temp           P_TempId
    ------------------------------------
    AN  #1001#.Test    5001,8001
    AN  #1001#.Test    5001,8001
    AN  #1002#.Test    5001,4001,7001,8001
    AN  #1002#.Test    5001,4001,7001,8001
    AN  #1002#.Test    5001,4001,7001,8001
```

Output:

```
        Id  Temp        P_TempId
        ---------------------------------------
        AN  #1001#.Test 5001,8001
        AN  #1002#.Test 5001,4001,7001,8001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** to number each set of `Id_Temp, P_TempId` and delete those numbered greater than 1.

```
;with cte as (
  select   
      *
    , rn = row_number() over (
            partition by Id, Temp, P_TempId
            order by (select 1)
            )
    from t
)
delete 
  from cte 
  where cte.rn > 1
```

or without the cte, using a standard subquery instead:

```
  delete s
  from (
    select   
        *
      , rn = row_number() over (
              partition by Id, Temp, P_TempId
              order by (select 1)
              )
    from t
    ) as s
  where s.rn > 1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CWO44915

returns:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+
| Id |    Temp     |      P_TempId       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
| AN | #1001#.Test | 5001,8001           |
| AN | #1002#.Test | 5001,4001,7001,8001 |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: @Charge Whoops, my mistake. I missed the `from` part in the subquery. corrected now.